# The server did not understand the operation that was requested. (aws)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using AdminGetUser endpoint to get user details but I'm getting an error.

```
{"code":"BadRequest","message":"The server did not understand the operation that was requested.","type":"client"}
```

Here I don't want to integrate SDK into a mobile app. So I'm integrating API in NodeJs.

url: [https://cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/AdminGetUser]

```
Headers:
Content-Type:application/x-amz-json-1.1
Accept:/
Action:admin-get-user
Version:2016-04-18
X-Amz-Algorithm:AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
X-AMZ-TARGET:com.amazonaws.cognito.identity.idp.model.AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.AdminGetUser
Authorization:AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<access_key>/20181013/us-east-1/cognito-idp/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-amz-target;x-amz-user-agent, Signature=<Signature>
x-amz-date:20181013T102730Z
```

Could you validate the above code.

Comment: ummm what code?

Comment: I mean the headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are calling is the SDK method called "AdminGetUser".

What you should be calling is any of the APIs listed here: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-userpools-server-contract-reference.html

Probably **/oauth2/userInfo** in your case.

Comment: Hi Deepthi. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I want to do all CURD operations using API's, but in AWS documentation we don't have all required Api's. Is there any way to do from node(without using sdk)?

Comment: I think everything mentioned here under https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-userpools-server-contract-reference.html should work for authentication scenarios.